# PHP DocComment template variable for method access

Tags: php, methods, comments

i was wondering if there is a template variable for the method visibility (e.g. @access public). I couldn't find anything, but there are even variables for the static keyword, so why not for access?

I thought something like ${ACCESS} would work, but it didn't.

So is there a predefined keyword for this or is there at least a way to define it myself?

Thanks for every answer in advance!

BTW: I'm using PHPStorm 6.0.1 on Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want autocompletion for docComment. When typing /** + Enter above a method, normally the whole comment gets generated. All but the @access prop. And thats what i'm looking for.

Comment: Would think that's IDE specific, what IDE are you using?